# Haproxy: no logs just for error requests, but ok for 200s

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, load-balancing, haproxy

I have a machine with Ubuntu 16.04.6 + Haproxy 1.6.3 (I know it's old but it is what it is) which is sending traffic to backend servers.

When I open the statistics page /haproxy?abc I can see an always growing number of Error > Req & it's ~10-15% of all requests. 7 389 on the screenshot: [image: haproxy stats]

But I'm not able to find any errors in the logs!
And I can definitely see lots of requests with status 200 in /var/log/haproxy.log

I have the following /etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf

```
global
  maxconn 100000
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  stats socket /run/haproxy/haproxy1.sock mode 660 level admin process 1
  stats socket /run/haproxy/haproxy2.sock mode 660 level admin process 2
  nbproc 2
  cpu-map 1 0
  cpu-map 2 1
  log /dev/log local0
  tune.maxrewrite  16384
  tune.bufsize     32768

defaults
  log global
  mode http
  option dontlognull
  option httplog
  option http-keep-alive
  option forwardfor
  option http-buffer-request
  retries 3
  option redispatch
  timeout http-request 30s
  timeout queue 1m
  timeout connect 10s
  timeout client 30s
  timeout server 30s
  timeout http-keep-alive 31s
  timeout check 10s
  maxconn 300000

frontend main
  bind *:80
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/ no-sslv3
  log-format "%ci:%cp [%tr] %HM %ST %HU body:%[capture.req.hdr(0)]"
  mode http
  option http-keep-alive
  stats enable
  stats uri /haproxy?abc
  stats realm Strictly\ Private
  stats auth xxxxx:yyyyyyyy
  declare capture request len 40000
  http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
  http-request capture req.body id 0
  http-response set-log-level err if { status 400:499 }
  acl  is_backend1  dst_port      80
  acl  is_backend1  dst_port      443
  use_backend     backend1    if  is_backend1
  default_backend   backend1

backend backend1
  mode http
  option forwardfor
  option httpchk HEAD /api/monitor
  http-check expect status 200
  http-request add-header X-Forwarded-For %[src]
  http-request add-header X-Real-Ip %[src]
  balance roundrobin
  maxconn 300000
  server xxxxxxxx 10.x.x.x:80 maxconn 100000 check inter 5000
  server yyyyyyyy 10.y.y.y:80 maxconn 100000 check inter 5000
```

Also I have the following /etc/rsyslog.d/49-haproxy.conf

```
$AddUnixListenSocket /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log

# Send HAProxy messages to a dedicated logfile
if $programname startswith 'haproxy' then /var/log/haproxy.log
&~
```

Logs in /var/log/haproxy.log look smth like that:

```
May 18 19:50:34 xxxxxxxx haproxy[4912]: xx.xxx.xx.x:32985 [] POST 200 /url/5a9ea5a0225f7d0004c70045/5ae0a5c0da5fdd00042f78f5/json body:{"url":"https://.............................................:[{".........................."}
May 18 19:50:08 xxxxxxxx haproxy[4913]: zz.zz.zzz.zzz:1802 [] OPTIONS 200 /url/5a9ea5a0225f7d0004c70045/5ae0a5c0da5fdd00042f78f5/json body:-
May 18 19:50:37 yyyyyyyy haproxy[4912]: yyy.yy.yy.yyy:21554 [] POST 200 /url/5a9ea5a0225f7d0004c70045/5ae0a5c0da5fdd00042f78f5/json body:{"url":"https://.............................................:[{".........................."}
```

Please help me find those error requests :)

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-logging/

Comment: @yoonix did you find any problems in my configuration, do you have any useful input?

Comment: If the documentation on logging for you isn't useful, then you're in the wrong place.  This isn't a configuration review service.

Comment: @yoonix I've used the docs but looks like I'm missing smth. Looks like you don't understand what's the purpose of serverfault, so please don't spam my question with your answers which don't help. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible these are connections which are opened but no data is sent? You seem to have dontlognull set, therefore empty requests will not be logged but may still produce an error? https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4-option%20dontlognull

Comment: "Here's what I have, tell me what's wrong" is not what serverfault is for.  You've shown no effort (in the posting).  I posted what I thought would be a helpful link to get you going without any commentary whatsoever.  @GTXBxaKgCANmT9D9 Blow me.

Comment: @yoonix I've explained the problem + attached logs + configuration. You're wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Additional diagnostics showed that the errors go away if I disable health checks.
I've figured out that to be able to see logs for health checks you need to enable that functionality separately:

```
option log-health-checks
```

I will try that & a couple of more tricks & will edit this answer but with a high level of probability the health checks problems are the ones I need to look into.